# How to display product stock information in a single line per product with varying columns based on store count in Django?

Tags: python, django, pivot

I have 3 tables: Product, Store, Stock.
Stock contains the product's quantity and price.
Every Product has a Stock entry per store. If there 3 stores, each product will have 2 stock entry with their own price and quantity.

I want to display these records on a single line per product where the columns will depend on how many stores there is. Like this:

Product Name     Store1 Quantity   Store1 Price   Store2 Quantity   Store2 Price
Flathead Screw                10             60                20             70

How can I do this?

All I can give you now are my models:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    isactive= models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table="tblProductCategory"
        

class Product(models.Model):
    productid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,null=False,default=0)
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isactive= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table="tblProduct"

class Store(models.Model):
    storeid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    storename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table="tblStore"

class Stock(models.Model):
    stockid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,null=False,default=0)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,null=False,default=0)
    threshold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    discountprice = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stock = models.FloatField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        db_table="tblProductStock"
```

and my current view:

```
def get_product(request):
    recordsTotal = 0
    draw = int(request.GET['draw'])
    start = int(request.GET['start'])
    length = int(request.GET['length'])
    
    products = Stock.objects.all().select_related('product')
   
    recordsTotal = products.count()
    recordsFiltered = recordsTotal

    page =  start / length + 1

    paginator = Paginator(products, length)

    try:
        object_list = paginator.page(page).object_list
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        object_list = paginator.page(draw).object_list
    except EmptyPage:
        object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages).object_list

    data = ProductSerializer(object_list,many = True)

    json_res={
        "draw": draw,
        "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
        'data':data.data
    }

    return JsonResponse(json_res);
```

Can I use table pivot in this situation, if so how?